# How to download remote image then upload image as an image file for form submission?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, node-modules, form-data

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974487/how-to-download-an-image-as-stream-then-upload-it), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181758/how-to-upload-a-remote-image-in-node-request), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302043/node-js-how-to-post-image-along-with-request-data-to-another-server-api), but none help.

In Node, the goal is to use the axios module to download an image from Twitter then upload this image as an image file as part of a form submission.

This code downloads the Twitter image, but the uploaded binary image is corrupted when it reaches the server (also our server).

The image must be uploaded in binary.

A form is required because other fields are also submitted with the binary image. These other form fields were removed to simplify the code sample.

```
        const axios = require('axios');
        const FormData = require('form-data');

        let response = await axios.get('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EyGoZkzVoAEpgp9.png', {
                                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                             });

        let imageBuffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary');    
        let formData = new FormData();          
        formData.append('image', imageBuffer);

        try {
            let response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: serverUrl,
                data: formData,
            });

            // Do stuff with response.data

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "something fails between this step and performing the upload"? Can you share the error message?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan thanks for the reply. Updated the question: the image gets uploaded in a corrupted state. (Also the image must be uploaded in binary.)

Comment: Well how are you reading this data on the server? It seems odd to try and append the binary data into a form. Form post data won't typically accept this but, well it depends on how your server is processing the data

Comment: I'd suggest something more like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50543235/542251

Comment: @Liam thanks for the reply. Updated the question: a form is used because we submit other data along with the binary image. The other fields were removed in the code sample to simplify the code. Given that a form is required, do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot Can you see if adding `headers: formData.getHeaders()` to the Axios call changes anything?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan thanks for the idea, but it did not. any other suggestions? does it seem like the code should work?

Comment: Hi @ArunKumarMohan do you happen to have other suggestions? Are you available to offer Node consulting?

Comment: @Crashalot "do you happen to have other suggestions?" Can you update your question with a minimal reproducible script using a fake API or something? I can take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan sure, could I email you as the fake API would contain private details?

Comment: @Crashalot I was able to reproduce the issue using [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/) as the API.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Fiddler to look at the HTTP trace?

Answer (score 9):

You should pass the `headers` to the axios call using `formData.getHeaders()` to send a `Content-Type` header of `multipart/form-data`. Without it, a `Content-Type` header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is sent. You could pass a `responseType` of `stream` to the axios call that downloads the image and add the stream to the form data.

You can also use `axios.post` to simplify the method call.

```
const url = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EyGoZkzVoAEpgp9.png'
const { data: stream } = await axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'stream',
})

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('image', stream)

try {
  const { data } = await axios.post('http://httpbin.org/post', formData, {
    headers: formData.getHeaders(),
  })
  console.log(data)
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

[image: Edit Axios File Upload With Streams]

Comment: Should the input type be 'file' instead of 'image'?

Comment: @AlexRiveron Sorry, not sure if I understand. Are you referring to `'image'` passed to `formData.append`? If yes, it is the key and it could be any string. You can check the docs [here](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-).

Comment: Sorry Arun, that was my misunderstanding.

Comment: @AlexRiveron No worries.

Comment: Is the `stream` variable that you're passing to `formData.append` considered a `USVString` or `Blob`? According to the Mozilla Developer [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#append_parameters), if it's not either one of those or a subclass, it's converted to a string.

Comment: @AlexRiveron It's a readable stream. We're in Node land, btw. So, `USVString` and `Blob` don't exist. You could fork the linked CodeSandbox and play with it.

Comment: Thanks, will try this right now! You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetch API to fetch the image as a blob object and append it to form data. Then simply upload it to its destination using Axios, ajax, or the fetch API:

```
    const mediaUrl = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EyGoZkzVoAEpgp9.png"
    fetch(mediaUrl)
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        // you can also check the mime type before uploading to your server
        if (!['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'].includes(blob?.type)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid image');
        }

        // append to form data
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', blob);

        // upload file to server
        uploadFile(formData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Invalid image')
      });
```